# get avg of count in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying get the avg of the result of a count query, in the documentation of hive I read it is impossible and for this reason I try it:
1º

```
CREATE VIEW clicks_pais_totalView AS
SELECT p.pais as pais, count(1) as numeroClicks
FROM clicks_data_mat p
WHERE p.pais is not NULL
GROUP BY p.pais;
```

2º

```
CREATE TABLE clicks_pais_total AS SELECT * FROM clicks_pais_totalView;
ALTER TABLE clicks_pais_total CHANGE numeroClicks numeroClicksInt INT;
```

3º

```
SELECT pais as pais, avg(DISTINCT numeroclicksint)
FROM clicks_pais_total
GROUP BY pais;
```

The avg result always is the same the first query of count returned me, what is wrong?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing wrong query. If you count and avg the value, result will be always same because group by is same.

ex

tableA

```
name value
A     1
A     3
B     7
```

if you count by name

```
select name, count(1) from tableA
group by name;

A 2
B 1
```

then if you avg the value by name then it remains same because each name has single value, how it average. So

```
SELECT pais, avg(numeroClicks) from
FROM clicks_data_mat
WHERE pais is not NULL
group by pais;
```

Comment: Thanks by your help but in hive you can not chain nested expressions of aggregation, i.e., you can not do an average of a count. I know, strange so strange but I read that in the official documrntation of hive due to it I tried this other solution.

Comment: as I told you before, I implemented in first instance this query and dont work. Thanks.